# how to get a bot discord to respond on a specific text channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the bot to respond in a specific text channel, and not in the one where they wrote the message:
I tried with

```js
case 'provino':
  message.channel.find(channel => channel.name === "provino")
```

but then I wouldn't even know how to go on; I also searched for a video but I only find people using the ID of the text channel, which I don't know how to find on Discord.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the channel, like you did, and then assign the result to a new variable for further usage :

```
case 'provino':
    const newChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "provino");
    newChannel.send("Hello world.");
```

Comment: Answers with explanation makes them more acceptable + votable

Comment: ok thanks, it works, but I would also need to be able to tag the person who wrote that message, so that I can recognize it, the only thing that came to my mind is to use

`const user_provino = message.mentions.users.first ();`

but in this case I should ask to tag yourself to be able to use it, would you know a more effective way?

Comment: @BLY_Tambu I think this string is what you're trying to get :

`const user_provino = \`<@${message.author.id>}\`;`. This will mention the member that used the command if you send this in any channel :)